# Can I use a straight talk iPhone on Verizon's network?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

Can I use a straight talk iPhone (prepaid) on another carrier's network - specifically Verizon?

My understanding is that such a phone comes factory unlocked, so it should be possible.